# input type hidden using onclik

Tags: codeigniter, onclick

I have a problem when entering data into the database, where I want to enter the province_name attribute, but what is stored in the database is the id

my code

```
<div class="form-group col-md-4">
          <label>Province Name</label>
             <select name="province_order" id="provinsi" class="form-control select2" style="width: 100%;">
               <option value="0">-PILIH-</option>
                <?php foreach($data->result() as $row):?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $row->id_prov;?>"><?php echo $row->nama_provinsi;?></option>
                <?php endforeach;?>
            </select>
            <input type="text" name="province_order">
        </div>

  function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("provinsi").value;
  document.getElementById("klik").innerHTML = x;
}
```

nama_provinsi not save in database, but id save.
how to save the province__name attribute

Comment: So you want to save the `name` instead of the `id`? but isn't it redundant to save the `name` instead of the `id`?

Comment: yes, coz you put `value="<?php echo $row->id_prov;?>"`, if you want the name, you need to change to `value="<?php echo $row-> nama_provinsi;?>"`, but if you have a good db relationship you can relation it with the id

Answer (score 1):

Try this:-

```
<div class="form-group col-md-4">
      <label>Province Name</label>
         <select name="province_order" id="provinsi" class="form-control select2" style="width: 100%;">
           <option value="0">-PILIH-</option>
            <?php foreach($data->result() as $row):?>
                <option value="<?php echo $row->id_prov;?>" province="<?php echo $row->nama_provinsi;?>" ><?php echo $row->nama_provinsi;?></option>
            <?php endforeach;?>
        </select>
        <input type="text" name="province_order">
    </div>



function myFunction() {
  var x = $("#provinsi").attr('province');
  //document.getElementById("klik").innerHTML = x;
}
```